# Field-Type necessary for make query with polygons in Solr

Tags: java, solr

Now I have a field position described by:

```
Field:position
Type:location
Field-Type:org.apache.solr.schema.LatLonType
```

And this field is created in my solr document from java with this:

```
@Indexed(name = "position", type = "location")
private String position;
```

But when I want to make queries like that:

```
&q=*:*&fq={!field f=position}Intersects(POLYGON((-10 30, -40 40, -10 -20, 40 20, 0 0, -10 30)))
```

Doesn't work and I think the problem is with my `position` field type.

How I can resolve that? What kind of type is necessary to put in my java class?

The error is:

```
"error": {
    "msg": "Can't parse point 'Intersects(POLYGON((-10 30, -40 40, -10 -20, 40 20, 0 0, -10 30)))' because: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"Intersects(POLYGON((-10 30\"",
    "code": 400
  }
```

And whole response is:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 2,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "indent": "true",
      "fq": "{!field f=position}Intersects(POLYGON((-10 30, -40 40, -10 -20, 40 20, 0 0, -10 30)))",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1515490453401"
    }
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "Can't parse point 'Intersects(POLYGON((-10 30, -40 40, -10 -20, 40 20, 0 0, -10 30)))' because: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"Intersects(POLYGON((-10 30\"",
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

Solr version is 5.3.2 and JTS topology library is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed the library in your solr server?

because its LGPL license the JTS topology library it's not included in the solr distribution. In the solr help you have the guide to download and install: [Solr spatial search](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html#SpatialSearch-JTSandPolygons)

Comment: Good point. I tried what you said, so I copied the jts-core jar file to solr server location, but still doesn't work. Any another idea?

Comment: Did you reload the server? The solrconfig file also has some globs referencing what jars are loaded and maybe you have to add the reference to the lib there.

Comment: I use solr in docker container and I restart everything, docker container, docker, computer. Is another thing to do in this situation?

Comment: restarting the docker container should suffice, so you should check if the library it's loaded. The solr logs should help to verify if the library is loaded, and also should give more information in the error.

Comment: In logs I don't find a line with information about this .jar around the SolrConfig Adding specified lib dirs to ClassLoader line. How I can identify exactly if is loaded or no?

Comment: maybe you have to tune the log levels in solr and configure them as verbose.